# Get device token if user refuse Push notification ios

Tags: ios6, apple-push-notifications

I have set Push notification into my new app. I have heard it is not a good way to do but I get the device token using:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken
{


    NSString *deviceToken = [[newDeviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceToken = [deviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"###### DEVICE TOKEN = %@ #########",deviceToken); 


}
```

Everything is okay for me, nevertheless I use this token to log in a user into my base, but I have a problem: how can I get the device token if the user refuses to receive push notifications? How can I get the device token outside the App Delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the device token if the user does not agree to receive push notifications. The method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

will be called instead but you cannot get the token from that.

If you're looking for a unique identifer, you should consider using the *identifierForVendor*. See the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor

Answer (score 0):

This method will be called even if the user refuse to receive push notification. You can user UIRemoteNotificationType to get the user choice.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone){
        NSLog(@"User refused to receive push notifications");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"User agreed to receive push notifications");
    }
}
```

For your second question, you can't get the device token from iOS outside of this callback.

Comment: no this method is not called if user decline notifications . . . but thank you very much

Comment: It should not be but it is called. I have a live application with this code on the AppStore and I get deviceToken for users who refuse to receive push notifications (but of course, I can't send them push messages).

Comment: Actually, it seems the behavior changed on iOS7. The token is now sent only if the user accept push. You partially right because on prior version we could retrieve it before user made a choice, even if the user refused it..

Comment: maybe re-apprear but you still receive the token even if the user refuses In iOS 9